# 1984 Hilux won't crank

Tags: electrical, troubleshooting

My 30 year old Hilux won't turn over, all I get electronically is the horn and battery light. I've checked the fuses and hooked up a jump stater. No noise what so ever. Hasn't been started for a few years. I've taped the starter

Comment: Sitting for a year or more may introduce corrosion in electrical connections. Examine both battery cables and their connections, including grounds, have the battery tested or use a booster battery. If battery connections are clean and free of corrosion, you can try shorting two starter terminals together, the small terminal on the starter to the large one with the battery cable connection. This powers the starter solenoid to power up the starter. Leave ignition OFF for safety as all you're doing is testing if the starter operates or not (worn out).

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with that model, but sounds like a faulty ignition relay.

You could test this by identifying which relay it is (usually in the fuse box area) and trying to listen to it click when you turn the ignition (or by placing your finger on it and feeling it click).